# Calling delegate method through different classes in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am fetching JSON menu and once the JSON returned, I would like to **run menuReady() to update content of the table** within SomeTableViewController class. But the following code doesn't seems to work.

**AIM:** Run *menuReady()* to update content once JSON returned.

**PROBLEM:** *menuReady()* is never fired.

***SomeTableViewController.swift***

```
class SomeTableViewController: UITableViewController, MenuModelDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        menuModel.delegate = self
    }
    func menuReady() {
        // This is NOT fired.
        print("SomeViewController.menuReady()")
    }
}
```

***MenuModel.swift***

```
protocol MenuModelDelegate : class {
    func menuReady()
}

class MenuModel: NSObject {
    var delegate:MenuModelDelegate?
    func getMenu(data: JSON) {
        // This is fired.
        print("MenuModel.getMenu()")
        delegate?.menuReady()
    }
}
```

***Call from AnotherViewController when button tapped***

***AnotherViewController.swift***

```
class AnotherViewController : UIViewController {
    func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
        // This function is fired.
        // jsonData is some json data returned from http request
        let menuModel = MenuModel()
        menuModel.getMenu(data: jsonData)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `menuModel` in `SomeTableViewController` and the `menuModel` in "some other class" the exact same object?

Comment: @PhillipMills no, they are in separated object. Three different object.

Comment: So, the `MenuModel` object you're giving the delegate to is **not** the same as the one where you're calling the delegate method?

Comment: @PhillipMills They are not the same.

Comment: where do you call `getMenu(data: JSON)` method? I assume that you have to call it -somewhere in your code- to fire the delegate...

Comment: In that case, I don't understand why you expect `menuReady` **should** be fired.  Your code says to call it if the delegate in non-nil but, since you're giving the delegate to different object, it will be nil.

Comment: @AhmadF Called from some other class.

Comment: @PhillipMills Then how should I achieve the goal? I need to update SomeTableViewController after AnotherViewController finished something.

Comment: Then it could be the reason of causing the issue, you might need to mention how you are calling the method that calls the delegate.

Comment: @AhmadF I have refined the question.

Comment: You could pass the original model to `AnotherViewController`...perhaps, depending on your app structure.  You could send a notification to `SomeTableViewController` and let it call `getMenu`.  You could make `MenuModel` a singleton.  There are all kinds of options that work better or worse for different applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A delegate method is designed to work in a "one on one" relationship what you're trying to achieve here won't work as you have multiple different instances of `MenuModel` in different places. You should try initialising `MenuModel` as a property of `SomeTableViewController` and use it like the following:

```
class SomeTableViewController: UITableViewController, MenuModelDelegate {

    private let menuModel: MenuModel = MenuModel()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.menuModel.delegate = self
        self.menuModel.getMenu(data: jsonData)
    }
    func menuReady() {
        print("SomeTableViewController.menuReady()")
    }
}
```

If you're looking for a solution that will update multiple view controllers then a better solution would be to read up on `NotificationCenter`. Using notifications you can add observers to multiple view controllers/classes and simply get your `MenuModel` to post a notification.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @PhillipMills for pointing out the delegate object should be of the same object instance.

Here is the way solving the problem. Now the delegate function works fine.

***SomeTableViewController.swift***

```
class SomeTableViewController: UITableViewController, MenuModelDelegate {
    private let menuModel: MenuModel = MenuModel() // <--- Added property
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        menuModel.delegate = self
    }
    func menuReady() {
        print("menuReady")
    }
    // <--- Added Function
    func getModel() -> MenuModel {    
        return self.menuModel
    }
}
```

***MenuModel.swift***

```
protocol MenuModelDelegate : class {
    func menuReady()
    func getModel() -> MenuModel
}

class MenuModel: NSObject {
    var delegate:MenuModelDelegate?
    func getMenu(data: JSON) {
        print("getMenu()")
        delegate?.menuReady()
    }
}
```

***AnotherViewController.swift***

```
class AnotherViewController : UIViewController {
    func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
        // jsonData is some json data returned from http request
        // let menuModel = MenuModel() <--- Removed line

        /* You need to find a way to pass in someTableViewController
         * Use the menuModel defined in SomeTableViewController to
         * Call menuModel.getMenu() instead of defining a new menuModel */
        let menuModel = someTableViewController.getModel()
        menuModel.getMenu(data: jsonData)
    }
}
```